# array_diff converst array to stdClass Object

Tags: php

**$array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

**$array2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => three
)
```

**array_diff($array,$array2)**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)
```

**i need final result to be array instead of stdClass Object**

```
Array
(
        [0] => one
        [1] => two
)
```

Comment: `array_diff` does not return a stdClass object, but an array. Doing `var_dump(array_diff($array,$array2));` will give you exactly what you wanted `array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "one"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "two"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), its already returning an array.

> Compares array against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array that are not present in any of the other arrays.

To cast `stdClass` to array, can do

```
$casted_result = (array) $result;
```